# How to overload compare() in the subclass?

Tags: java, compare, comparator

I'm trying do to simple exercises about Comparators in Java. I created two classes: Employee and Manager. In the Employee class I compared two istances by the salary.

```
class Employee implements Comparator <Employee>{
  private String name;
  private int salary;
    Employee (String n, int s)  {
    this.name = n;
    this.salary = s;
  }

  public String getName (){
    return this.name;
  }

  public int getSalary ()  {
    return this.salary;
  }

  @Override 
  public int compare (Employee d, Employee d2)  {   //compare by the salary
    return d.getSalary () - (d2.getSalary ());
  }
}
```

And it works fine because I tried with this:

```
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    Employee e = new Employee ("carl", 1000);
    Employee e2 = new Employee ("sam", 1000);
    Comparator<Employee> ce = new Employee("a", 0);
    System.out.println (ce.compare(e,e2));   //returns 0 because e and e2 have the same salary  
  }
```

Now, in my Manager class I added a new attribute named "bonus". I would like to compare two istances by the bonus. This is my implementation:

```
class Manager extends Employee {
  private Integer bonus;
    Manager (String n, int s, Integer b)  {
    super (n, s);
    this.bonus = b;
  }

  public int compare (Manager a, Manager b)  {
    return a.bonus.compareTo(b.bonus);
  }

}
```

I know that Manager class extends Employee but also it implements Comparator< Employee >(am I right?). But in the implementation it seems that "compare" method isn't from Comparator interface. Infact if I remove the public visibility it doesn't give me errors. This is my main for Manager class:

```
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    Manager m = new Manager ("mary", 1000, 100);
    Manager m2 = new Manager ("liza", 1000, 200);

    Comparator<Employee> cm = new Manager("a", 0, 0);
    
    System.out.println (cm.compare(m,m2)); //returns 0. it compares by salary

  }
```

It compares the manager by the salary and not by the bonus.
Can you help me to understand why? Thank you.

EDIT: I changed the title.

Comment: If the object itself has a natural order, it should `implements Comparable<...>`, not `implements Comarator<...>`.

Comment: `Comparator<Employee> cm` only has one method: `compare(Employee, Employee)`. Method `compare(Manager, Manager)` in `Manager` odes not override, but overload  `compare(Employee, Employee)` in class `Employee`.

Comment: Ok but if I want my custom order? I should implement Comparator. Am I right?

Comment: You can't override `compare(To)` for subclasses without violating the contract of `Comparator/Comparable`, because you break the symmetry requirement.

Comment: Custom sorting should be done *outside* the class, using a separate `Comparator` object.  See [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,java.util.Comparator)).